# Using git-lfs-transfer with groups

Tags: git, git-lfs

I have compiled `git-lsf-transfer` from https://github.com/bk2204/scutiger so I can transfer big files for lsf via ssh instead of https.

It works. However, it only works when the repo is actually owned by the user calling the git command (and thus executing the ssh). when I change the ownership of the repo to the group/user `git`  (to which my user belongs), lsf transfer fails with the message that the user is not the owner of the repo.

How do I configure git-lsf-transfer in such a way that it will understand I am a member of the group that owns  the repo?

### Debugging details

When performing `git push` I get the following msg:

```
batch request: bash: line 1: git-lfs-authenticate: command not found: exit status 127                                                        
error: failed to push some refs to '{host ip}:/mnt/data/git-repos/tst.git'
```

After researching I learned that git-lfs-authenticate gets called because git-lfs-transfer fails.

Then performing git push with tracing details (`GIT_TRACE_PACKET=true GIT_SSH_VARIANT=simple GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_TRANSFER_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git push`)

```
...
11:53:55.020553 trace git-lfs: exec: git 'config' '--includes' '-l' '--blob' 'HEAD:.lfsconfig'
11:53:55.025721 trace git-lfs: attempting pure SSH protocol connection
11:53:55.025742 trace git-lfs: spawning pure SSH connection
11:53:55.025806 trace git-lfs: run_command: ssh {host ip} git-lfs-transfer /mnt/data/git-repos/tst.git upload
11:53:55.026081 trace git-lfs: exec: ssh '{host ip}' 'git-lfs-transfer /mnt/data/git-repos/tst.git upload'
11:53:57.797163 trace git-lfs: pure SSH connection successful
11:53:57.797176 trace git-lfs: pure SSH protocol connection failed: Unable to negotiate version with remote side (unable to read capabilities): EOF
11:53:57.797986 trace git-lfs: pre-push: refs/heads/master c038a0e6a57beae72c25efeccfe5cf0f516ad330 refs/heads/master e28e585285e828041442ac2e4b24b38340d3aa60
11:53:57.798080 trace git-lfs: exec: git '-c' 'filter.lfs.smudge=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.clean=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.process=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.required=false' 'show-ref'
...
```

From this trace I got the ssh command that is used to call git-lfs-transfer.

Subsequently I reproduced the error using the following command (based on the trace):

```
ssh {host ip} git-lfs-transfer /mnt/data/git-repos/tst.git upload
```

Resulting in the following error:

```
repository path '/mnt/data/git-repos/tst.git/' is not owned by current user; class=Config (7); code=Owner (-36)
```

### Work around

So, this happens when the owner of the repo is `git:git`. When I change it to `dstibbe:dstibbe` (my account) it works. `dstibbe` is member of the group `git`.

Comment: Can you please include the exact error message produced as a code block?

Comment: added error message (awesome that you yourself are reacting, if you need any more details, just let me know)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because Scutiger, like the Git LFS local repository adapter, needs to look up the location of the `.git` directory and, for Scutiger, the configuration.  Neither Git nor libgit2 will operate on a repository which is owned by another user without a suitable configuration option, and libgit2, which Scutiger uses, cannot override this functionality.

In theory, Git itself could be configured to allow these two pieces of functionality, and I have a branch that switches to using Git.  However, while I, as a Git developer, know that these two pieces of functionality are currently secure, there's no guarantee that they'll remain so in the future.  Thus, if we enabled this functionality, a future version of Git might change and then we'd have a security vulnerability.

I've [opened a discussion on the Git list](https://lore.kernel.org/git/ZZr-JLxubCvWe0EU@tapette.crustytoothpaste.net/T/#u) to see if there's agreement on improving this situation.  I've gotten the impression from talking to folks that this probably is valuable, but it's not necessarily super trivial to do, so some discussion is warranted.

Comment: "either Git nor libgit2 will operate on a repository which is owned by another user  ... " ,  however Git has no issue with the fact that my repo is owned by the group I belong to ('git') and not by my user ('dstibbe'). Or  am I misunderstanding your comment?

Comment: Recent versions of Git will not operate on repositories that are not owned by the current user.  Some older versions may do so, but both Git and Git LFS have been patched not to do so for security reasons.

Comment: Odd decision from Git, but clear explanation. Thank you